# Use data from mysql db to present the number of active concurrent processes at a given time in a html table

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop, procedural-programming

I have a dataset in my db like this showing start times of processes and the duration in seconds:

```
+---------------------+----------+
| start_time          | duration |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2013-10-01 10:00:00 |     15.6 |
| 2013-10-01 10:00:03 |      0.8 |
| 2013-10-01 10:00:03 |      4.5 |
| 2013-10-01 10:00:14 |     22.8 |
| 2013-10-01 10:00:28 |     30.9 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

With this data, I would like to be able display a table in the browser at an interval of every 15 secs to see how many processes are active at the specified interval. The user will be able to specify a date and time range so the query can be used like this:

```
SELECT start_time, duration FROM process_period
WHERE start_time >= "2013-10-01 10:00:00" AND start_time < "2013-10-24 11:00:00"
```

What would be the best approach to take for this?
The desired output should be this:

```
Interval time:               Number of active processes:
2013-10-01 10:00:00                      1
2013-10-01 10:00:15                      2
2013-10-01 10:00:30                      2
2013-10-01 10:00:45                      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two things in your query. To calculate number of process started in particular time use "GROUPBY" and to set interval use "HAVING". Since you are using "GROUPBY", "WHERE" clause is not possible in your query.
Check followinf fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a82fa/4/0

Edit: Or If you want process count in particular interval, then do as follows

```
select count(*) as process_count from processdata where start_time between '2013-10-01 10:15:00' and '2013-10-01 10:23:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I want to use the interval so i can show how many processes are active at the x interval?